# upgrade neovim 0.8.3 to 0.9.0 and font-hack-nerd-font, the font displayed by number appears overflow

Tags: neovim, plugin

Updated neovim 0.8.3 => 0.9.0 and font-hack-nerd-font. use https://github.com/folke/todo-comments.nvim plugin and Hack Nerd Font, config font_size=12, the font displayed by number appears overflow. As shown below, the insertion cursor is positioned in the middle of the tick box.

Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid this should be discussed with Neovim development team. This forum is to answer configuration question in general but not bug reports.